# Python Playwright - Want to print all text in <table> but finds 0 rows

Tags: python, web-scraping, playwright, playwright-python

I want to print all text in  rows () with the help of Python and Playwright but on the specific website I'm trying to scrape it always finds 0 rows in the table, even though it has multiple ones.

[want to scrape the trs in this tbody](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KL29W.png)

[This is my current code. It always just gives me 0 or "[]"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdtMk.png)

```
    #locate elements
            table = page.locator('table.contenttable')
            rows = table.locator("tbody tr")
            #try to print, gives me 0
            print(rows.all_text_contents())
            cols = rows.locator("td")
            #try to print, gives me 0
            print(cols.inner_text())

            #try to print, gives me 0
            index = 0

            print(rows.count())

            while index < rows.count():
                print("Got here")
                print(rows.nth(index).inner_text())
                index =+ 1
```

Answer (score 1):

To extract the full text from a table, create a locator for all lines and then extract the text from each line in a loop.

```
rows = page.locator('table#contenttable tr')
for i in range(rows.count()):
    print(rows.nth(i).inner_text())
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also use nth on the locator (of the row) and set the index on that

```
cols = rows.locator("td >> nth=index")
```